# make pair of arrays from list of array [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$arr = ['A','B','C', 'D'];
```

How can I divide it into a set of pairs like this?

```
$output = [
0 => [
        0 => 'A',
        1 => 'B'
]
1 => [
        0 => 'B',
        1 => 'C',
]
2 => [
        0 => 'C',
        1 => 'D'
]
```

Comment: no this is not homework assignment I am a beginner and I am stuck with one problem I have to make this type of array to proceed to my next part of the code.

Comment: So have a look at the `for` loop. You would want to loop over the initial array and build your new array.

Comment: ok sir, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : Array Slice issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620784/php-array-slice-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_slice` could be useful for this. Since you're selecting pairs you'll need to stop the loop at the second-to-last element.

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($arr) - 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $result[] = array_slice($arr, $i, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your help